# How do I make a formula in Notion with two conditions?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, formula, notion-api

I have two select fields in Notion, "Reqs Status" and "Figma Status". I want to create a formula that says if the content of both of these fields is "Ready" that the formula field should display "Ready for Development." I tried the following:

```
if (prop("Reqs Status") == "Ready" and prop("Figma Status") =="Ready", "Ready for Development")
```

However, Notion says: "Too few arguments in function if"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. I had to make a few tweaks. Here's what I came up with:

```
if(and(prop("Reqs Status") == "Ready", prop("Figma Status") == "Ready"), "Ready for Development", "In Progress")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the result of false, for example:

`if (prop("Reqs Status") == "Ready" and prop("Figma Status") =="Ready", "Ready for Development", "not ready yet")`